# How can I connect multiple I2S devices to STM32H7?

Tags: stm32, embedded, stm32cubemx

I am building an audio application using STM32H7 to communicate with two 32 bits SRC (Sample Rate Converters), two 24 bits CODECs, one 32 bits ADC and two 24 bits DAC.

I want to receive audio data from the ADC and CODECs, apply DSP algorithms and send the audio data to the DAC and CODECs. The STM32 should receive data from one SRC-1 and send data to SRC-2.

Given that STM32 has only 3 I2S interfaces, how can I connect these 6 devices to the STM32H7?

In this [document](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/technical-articles/ms-2275.pdf), it says that TDM protocol supports multiple channels.

How can I configure the STM32 in CubeMX to support multiple devices in TDM mode?

If i use the following connection diagram below:
[image: CODECS]
then how do i connect the SDIN and SDOUT pins of the 3<sup>rd</sup>, 4<sup>th</sup> and N<sup>th</sup> devices?

Comment: The problem is 3 I2S peripherals will never be enough for 9 I2S chips. Does your chips support TDM mode? Why does the data need to pass through STM32 anyway?

Comment: I made a mistake in the diagram.

Comment: Which STM32 exactly? The 'H7 has SAI peripheral(s) which is I2S-capable.

Comment: @wek it's the STM32H757XIH6. I noticed SAI peripherals as well. So I guess I can use the 3 I2S peripherals and SAI peripherals in I2S mode simultaneously right?

Comment: _I can use the 3 I2S peripherals and SAI peripherals in I2S mode simultaneously_ Yes.